# gitweb vs git-log date

Tags: git, git-log, gitweb

I currently have a local clone of a repo from our company git server. What I have noticed is that the dates returned in the history summary returned by `git log` don't match the dates on our gitweb server view.

Can anyone explain how each of these gets their dates and possibly why they might be different?

Having different dates makes it very complicated to track changes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer:

One is the author date and one is the commit date.

The following blog made this very clear to me:

http://www.alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git/